# Jquery datepicker closing automatically

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I am using from date text box and a calender button. When I click on calender button I should get datepicker from which i can select date.

Following is my code

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenDatePicker() {
        $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID %>").datepicker({ changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            duration: "slow",
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            closeText: "X",
            showButtonPanel: true,
            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) { $("#<%=tbFromDate.ClientID %>").val(dateText); $(this).datepicker("hide"); },
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID %>").blur();
            }
        });

    }      

</script>
```

Aspx code :

```
<div id="datepicker" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbFromDate"></asp:TextBox><asp:ImageButton runat="server"  ID="ibtnDateFrom" ImageUrl="~/Images/date.gif" OnClientClick="javascript:OpenDatePicker();" /></div>
```

When I run code and click on button datepicker opens for less than second or something and closes and page is refreshed.

Whats wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the ImageButton causing a Postback. You can just use an Image, and apply a css style on it to display the hand cursor on hover.

Comment: I am using Image now...but again it works for first time..and nothing happens on second click. I am not returning false.

Answer (score 1):

Your page performs a postback when you click an ImageButton.

1- You can use Image instead of ImageButton. 
 2- You can place return false in OpenDatePicker function to prevend postback.  
 3- You can use datepicker's built-in Image support.

```
   function OpenDatePicker() {
                        $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID %>").datepicker({ 
                            buttonImage: "../Images/date.gif",
                            changeMonth: true,
                            changeYear: true,
                            duration: "slow",
                            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                            closeText: "X",
                            showButtonPanel: true,
                            onSelect: function (dateText, inst) { $("#<%=tbFromDate.ClientID %>").val(dateText); $(this).datepicker("hide"); },
                            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                                $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID %>").blur();
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

place a statement return false; in your OpenDatePicker() function

```
function OpenDatePicker() {
    $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID %>").datepicker({ changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        duration: "slow",
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        closeText: "X",
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) { $("#<%=tbFromDate.ClientID %>").val(dateText); $(this).datepicker("hide"); },
        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
            $("#<%=datepicker.ClientID %>").blur();
        }
    });
return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried it.. It works fine for first time... if I select date and remove focus calender hides (which is correct), But if I want to change selected date I have to click again on calender button but even after clicking on it nothing happens..

Answer (score 0):

Show you calendar button code..is it input type=submit ? on click of calendar button you must be calling a method..which can be OpenDatePicker() function..add return false or event.preventDefault() for prohibiting default form submission.

Answer (score 0):

try following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
            $("#<%= tbFromDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            duration: "slow",
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            closeText: "X",
            showButtonPanel: true
            });

            $("#<%= ImageButton1.ClientID %>").click(function() {
              $("#<%= tbFromDate.ClientID %>").datepicker('show');
            });
        });
    </script>


    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbFromDate"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/date.gif"/>
```

Hope this helps